# Socket.io Namespace has no method adaptor

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am creating application where i am need of creating dynamic namespaces. when ever i create a new namespace, i am attaching redis-adapter to it for scaling purpose. By doing this i am getting following error.

```
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
        path:"/stream",
        transports:['websocket']
    });
var nsp = io.of('namespace1')
nsp.adapter(redis({host:"host", port:"port"}))
```

TypeError: nsp.adapter is not a function

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As per doc, you need to attach adapter to socket.io once.
(https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)

```
io.adapter(redis({host:"host", port:"port"}))
```

Comment: I'm doing this but I'm still getting an error.  TypeError: this.adapter.add is not a function